# Corda : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This AttachmentWithContext was not initialised properly

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

We have a custom Implementation of Nonfungible token state and Nonfungible token contract in our project. We are using the below piece of code to issue our custom non fungible token.

```
        Party notary = NotaryUtilitiesKt.getPreferredNotary(getServiceHub(),NotaryUtilitiesKt.firstNotary());
        TransactionBuilder transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
        IssueTokensUtilitiesKt.addIssueTokens(transactionBuilder, tokensToIssue);
        FlowUtilitiesKt.addTokenTypeJar(tokensToIssue, transactionBuilder);
```

when trying to convert the above obtained transaction builder to a wired transaction( `builder.toWireTransaction(serviceHub);`) we are getting an error with the below stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This AttachmentWithContext was not initialised properly. Please ensure all Corda contracts extending existing Corda contracts also implement the Contract base class.
    at net.corda.core.internal.AttachmentWithContext.<init>(AttachmentWithContext.kt:18)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.handleContract(TransactionBuilder.kt:487)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.selectContractAttachmentsAndOutputStateConstraints(TransactionBuilder.kt:359)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext(TransactionBuilder.kt:159)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransactionWithContext$core(TransactionBuilder.kt:146)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toWireTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:140)
```

Comment: The exception says that you have a problem with your custom contract implementation. Does it implement the base Contract interface? https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/tut-two-party-contract.html#the-contract-interface

Answer (score 1):

Like Alesandro said, the error does seem to point to a contract class issue.

> Please ensure all Corda contracts extending existing Corda contracts also implement the Contract base class.

I'd double check that your contract class does implement contract correctly. Something like this:

```
class IOUContract : Contract {
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    val IOU_CONTRACT_ID = "net.corda.training.contracts.IOUContract"
}
```

source: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/contracts-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/training/contracts/IOUContract.kt

Good luck!